# Efficient implementation of SOM (Self organizing map) on Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, som

I am struggling with the implementation of a performant version of a SOM Batch algorithm on Spark / Pyspark for a huge dataset with > 100 features.
I have the feeling that I can either use RDDs where I can/have to specifiy the parallization on my own or I use Dataframe which should be more performant but I see no way how to use something like a local accumulation variable for each worker when using dataframes.

Ideas:

- Using Accumulators. Parallelize the calculations by creating a UDF which takes the observations as input, calculates the impacts on the net and sends the impacts to an accumulator in the driver. (Implemented this version already, but seems rather slow (I think accumulator updates take to long))
- Store results in a new column of Dataframe and then sum it together in the end. (Would have to store a whole neural net in the each row (e.g. 20*20*130) tho) Are spark optimization algorithms realizing, that it does not need to save each net but only sum them together?
- Create an custom parallized algorithms using RDDs similar to that: https://machinelearningnepal.com/2018/01/22/apache-spark-implementation-of-som-batch-algorithm/ (but with more performant calculation algorithms). But I would have to use some kind of loop to loop over each row and update the net -> sounds like that would be rather unperformant.)

Any thoughts on the different options? Is there an even better option?

Or are all ideas not that good and I should just preselect a maximum variety subset of my dataset and train a SOM locally on that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what I have done last year, so I might be in a good position to give you an answer.

First, [here is my Spark implementation of the batch SOM algorithm](https://github.com/FlorentF9/sparkml-som) (it is written in Scala, but most things will be similar in Pyspark).

I needed this algorithm for a project, and every implementation I found had at least one of these two problems or limitations:

- they did not really implement the batch SOM algorithm, but used a map averaging method that gave me strange results (abnormal symmetries in the output map)
- they did not use the DataFrame API (pure RDD API) and were not in the Spark ML/MLlib spirit, i.e. with a simple `fit()`/`transform()` API operating over DataFrames.

So, there I went on to code it myself: the batch SOM algorithm in Spark ML style. The first thing I did was looking how k-means was implemented in Spark ML, because as you know, the batch SOM is very similar to the k-means algorithm. Actually, I could re-use a large portion of the Spark ML k-means code, but I had to modify the core algorithm and the hyperparameters.

I can summarize quickly how the model is built:

1. A `SOMParams` class, containing the SOM hyperparameters (size, training parameters, etc.)
2. A `SOM` class, which inherits from spark's `Estimator`, and contains the training algorithm. In particular, it contains a `fit()` method that operates on an input `DataFrame`, where features are stored as a `spark.ml.linalg.Vector` in a single column. `fit()` will then select this column and unpack the `DataFrame` to obtain the unerlying `RDD[Vector]` of features, and call the `run()` method on it. This is where all the computations happen, and as you guessed, it uses `RDD`s, accumulators and broadcast variables. Finally, the `fit()` method returns a `SOMModel` object.
3. `SOMModel` is a trained SOM model, and inherits from spark's `Transformer`/`Model`. It contains the map prototypes (center vectors), and contains a `transform()` method that can operate on `DataFrames` by taking an input feature column, and adding a new column with the predictions (projection on the map). This is done by a prediction UDF.
4. There is also `SOMTrainingSummary` that collects stuff such as the objective function.

Here are the take-aways:

- There is not really an opposition between `RDD` and `DataFrame`s (or rather `Dataset`s, but the difference between those two is of no real importance here). They are just **used in different contexts**. In fact, a DataFrame can be seen as a `RDD` specialized for manipulating structured data organized in columns (such as relational tables), allowing SQL-like operations and an optimization of the execution plan (Catalyst optimizer).
- For structured data, select/filter/aggregation operations, DO USE `Dataframe`s, always.
- ...but for more complex tasks such as a machine learning algorithm, you NEED to come back to the `RDD` API and distribute your computations yourself, using map/mapPartitions/foreach/reduce/reduceByKey/and so son. Look at how things are done in MLlib: it's only a nice wrapper around RDD manipulations!

Hope it will solve your question. Concerning performance, as you asked for an *efficient* implementation, I did not make any benchmarks yet but I use it at work and it crunches 500k/1M-rows datasets in a couple of minutes on the production cluster.